# Strange error when assigning a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
byte[] frame_to_send= new byte[6];
// code  

frame_to_send = { 0x68, 0x04, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; `//Array edit`
```

Error:

> Invalid expression term '{'
>   ; expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only do this at construction time initialization:

```
byte[] frame_to_send = { 0x68, 0x04, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

At any later time you can only do it like that:

```
frame_to_send = new byte[]{ 0x68, 0x04, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

*Note* that in the code you show you at first create a byte array with all values set to 0, and then (try to) create a new one, discarding the formerly created completely. So your initial assignment is totally redundant.

Comment: @Fabjan No, the compiler interpretes the literals as `int` and can't convert a `int[]` into a `byte[]`. Tried it ;)

Comment: And that, ladies and gentlemen, is why, on top of making the code bloody unreadable, leaving out types is a bad idea :)

Comment: Yea, you're right, just forgot that by default it creates `int` array, upvoted your answer anyway

Comment: @Nyerguds You're not leaving out type if it was declared just a line above. It's very clear what type is there in most cases. But in this example 10 may be of type `byte` or `int` or even `long`, so we should declare type explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't have an array literal syntax like that. It is only on construction time you can do that.

Adjust your code to be:

```
byte[] frame_to_send= new byte[] { 0x68, 0x04, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

Comment: No real need of explicit type in right side of expression, `byte[] frame_to_send = { .. };` should work fine

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your array after declaring it, then you will need to access it element by element.

byte[] frame_to_send = new byte[6];

frame_to_send[0] = 0x68;
frame_to_send[1] = 0x04;
frame_to_send[2] = 0x83;
frame_to_send[3] = 0x00;
frame_to_send[4] = 0x00;
frame_to_send[5] = 0x00;

You can always use loop to do it.

Comment: The loop would inevitably access a different, already existing array though, in which case `Array.Copy(data_containing_array, frame_to_send, frame_to_send.Length)` is a much simpler solution than a loop.

Comment: That was a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
byte[] frame_to_send = new byte[] { 0x68, 0x04, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```